# 1-Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error. 2-Failed to find style 'floatingActionButtonStyle' in current theme

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-appcompat

1-Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.

2-Failed to find style 'floatingActionButtonStyle' in current theme.

Xml file shows the above two error along with the following -

1-Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

2-The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer

- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView

- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar

- android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

classpath is:

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'



dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//add library
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services
```

XML file-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"

tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    />
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Message..."
        android:inputType="text" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_of_message"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fab"
    android:dividerHeight="16dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste these two dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
```

the beta version is causing the Problem.

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Comment: Try Lowering version of the Dependencies.